# How can I refer one YAML file from another?

Tags: yaml

I have a YAML file, which I want to refer into a different YAML file. Is this possible, if yes, if someone can help me with the syntax or examples? Would be great help

Answer (score 1):

Each YAML document is self-contained and thus cannot refer to any external data or resource. YAML doesn't even know the concept of files; YAML documents are contained in a *stream* which might be a file, a network socket, anything.

Various YAML users employ various techniques to refer to outside content, like OpenAPI's [$ref](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref/) or Ansible's and Helm's preprocessing with templating engines. However all those features are only supported in their respective environments and are not YAML features.

If you are in control of the code loading the YAML file, you can of course implement your own method. If you are *not* in control of the code loading the YAML file, all you can do is either depend on whatever features the loading code offers, or manually preprocess your YAML with some templating engine to produce a single merged YAML file which you then hand over to the loading code.